# Значение переменной не сохраняется

Tags: php, html

Помогите найти ошибку!
    session_start();

```
$user_id=(int)$_SESSION['id'];
$news_id=$_GET["id"]; //здесь переменная $news_id существует и имеет значение

//тут какой-то код
if (что-то)  //в этом блоке переменная $news_id существует
echo "<form action=\"%этот же файл%.php\" method=\"POST\">
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"proch\" value=\"Прочитано\">
</form>";

//тут какой-то код

if (isset($_POST['proch']))//обработка нажатия кнопки
{//тут переменная user_id существует, news_id -нет. (имеет 0)
$query="INSERT INTO otm ( user_id , news_id ) value ('$user_id','$news_id')";
if (mysql_query($query)==true) echo "Сделано, хозяин!";
}
```

Почему значение переменной $user_id сохраняется во всех блоках файла, а $news_id в 3-м блоке отсутствует?
Битых 1.5 часа копаюсь, не могу найти ошибку!

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: очевидно $news_id обнуляется там где 

    //тут какой-то код

телепатически можно предположить нечто вроде 

    if ($news_id=0) {}

Comment: вы в курсе, что у вас там sql injection в коде ?

Comment: if ($news_id=0) {}
Таких инструкций нету, на сервере, к сожалению стоит php 5.2.17. Почему не поставлю php 5.5.0 - имеются некоторые проблемы совместимости.
Поподробнее, пожалуйста, чем плоха sql injection в коде?

Comment: Все, понял про sql injection, спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому как в одном случае у вас применяется метод $_GET, в другом, метод $_POST, поэтому переменная $news_id не существует для $_POST.
Посмотрит различие между глобальными массивами POST, GET в сети.

Предлагаю передавать значение $_GET["id"] в виде $_POST["id"]. Тогда сделайте скрытое поле input для сохранения этого id и дальнейшего сабмита формы.

Comment: Тоже думал о чем-то подобном, попробую сегодня.